# Appendix with two chapters and two counters

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I would like to create two successive appendices for my current project.
They're supposed to be formatted like this:

```
Appendix A

A.1 Random Section 

A.2 Random Section

Appendix B

B.1 Random Section
```

But my current output looks like this:

```
Appendix A

A.1 Random Section 

A.2 Random Section

Appendix B

A.3 Random Section
```

I guess I missunderstand something very simply concerning \setcounter and \addcontentsline. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,BCOR5mm, DIV=12]{scrreprt}

    \begin{document}

        \appendix
        \chapter*{Anhang A\markboth{Anhang A}{Anhang A}}
        \setcounter{chapter}{1}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Anhang A}

        \section{Literaturverzeichnis}

        \chapter*{Anhang B\markboth{Anhang B}{Anhang B}}
        \setcounter{chapter}{1}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Anhang B}

        \section{Tabellenverzeichnis}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you using `\chapter*` and add the title manually to the ToC? Your `\setcounter{chapter}` does of course not reset the `section` counter and you will get into troubles with `hyperref` and hyperlinks this way (in case you should be using it)

Comment: Because by using `\chapter*` I get "Appendix A" instead of "A Appendix A". But you've already posted the right answer, I wasn't aware of  `\stepcounter{chapter}`. Thank you :)

Comment: Well, consider the `appendix` package for such cases to remove `Appendix`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\stepcounter{chapter}` and the counter resetting chain of `section` etc. comes into action -- this is not the case for `\setcounter{chapter}{1}`.

Of course, `\setcounter{chapter}{1}` will always fix the chapter number to be `1` and therefore, `A.1` is printed, etc.

The whole issue would not occur, if `\chapter` would be used, instead of `\chapter*`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,BCOR5mm, DIV=12]{scrreprt}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\appendix

\stepcounter{chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Anhang A}
\chapter*{Anhang A\markboth{Anhang A}{Anhang A}}

\section{Literaturverzeichnis}

\section{\LaTeXe\ lernen}

\stepcounter{chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Anhang B}
\chapter*{Anhang B\markboth{Anhang B}{Anhang B}}

\section{Tabellenverzeichnis}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

A cleaner way with the `appendix` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,BCOR5mm, DIV=12]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\begin{appendices}

\chapter{Anhang A}
\section{\bibname}

\section{\LaTeXe\ lernen}
\chapter{Anhang B}

\section{\listtablename}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `\chapter*`, there is no increment of the chapter counter, which is typically followed by a resetting of the sub-sectional level counters.

In the example below I've re-ordered the sequence of commands to make more sense (even if you later decide to use [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)).

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Anhang A}
\chapter*{Anhang A}\markboth{Anhang A}{Anhang A}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{A}\stepcounter{chapter}

\section{Literaturverzeichnis}

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Anhang B}
\chapter*{Anhang B}\markboth{Anhang B}{Anhang B}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{B}\stepcounter{chapter}

\section{Tabellenverzeichnis}

\end{document}
```

You could also, as an alternative, adjust the way `\thesection` is printed rather than setting `\thechapter`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a reason for using all these `\markboth`s and starred `\chapter`s with `\addcontentsline`, but you could do it a lot easier without. just use a non-starred `\chapter` and it will be just fine.

If you really need them, just moving the `\setcounter` one line up solves it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,BCOR5mm, DIV=12]{scrreprt}

    \begin{document}
\tableofcontents
        \appendix
        \chapter*{Anhang A\markboth{Anhang A}{Anhang A}}
        \setcounter{chapter}{1}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Anhang A}

        \section{Literaturverzeichnis}

        \setcounter{chapter}{2}
        \chapter*{Anhang B\markboth{Anhang B}{Anhang B}}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Anhang B}

        \section{Tabellenverzeichnis}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: This solves the `A` and `B` counter output issue, but not the missing reset of the `section` counter